# Using VMs on an external HDD as nodes of a Hadoop cluster

Tags: unix, hadoop, virtual-machine

I am a newbie to both Hadoop and Virtual Machine(VM). I would like to have a Hadoop cluster with 4-5 nodes. What I understand is that each node is a commodity hardware(PC running Unix). My thought is, is it possible to create 4-5 Virtual Machines(VMs) on an external HDD and use them as nodes for a Hadoop cluster and hoist big data applications on them? If so, what are the general steps I take to achieve this VM based Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be plain wrong.

The idea of clustering is to increase the available computational power by using *multiple* physical machines and let them communicate in a manner that allows the overall problem to be split among them.

Now, if you just use four or five VMs on the same physical PC, you're not getting more CPU power than what you'd get if you'd just let your stuff run locally with only a single node -- you're getting less.

Comment: Marcus, Thx, that makes a lot of sense, however, I was wondering as to how they do it on Amazon ECS Cloud and such other platforms? Any input on that??

Comment: well, they have the opposite situation: do more application on less physical CPU, not doing more physical CPU for one application. Really, you need to read up on what all these technologies are meant for, @Raghu.